# remove all <br> from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that i would like to remove all occurrences of `<br>`

I tried this and it did not work.

```
    productName = productName.replace("<br>"," ");
```

However this worked but only for the first `<br>`

```
    productName = productName.replace("&lt;br&gt;"," ");
```

How would I get it to work for all `<br>` in the string.

Edit: this is the string...

`00-6189 Start Mech Switch&lt;br&gt;00-6189 Start Mech Switch&lt;br&gt;00-6189 Start Mech Switch&lt;br&gt;`

My apologies for being a little misleading with the `<br>` as it should have been `&lt;br&gt;`

Comment: If you use my pattern you can write either < or &lt;, > or &gt; i

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like your string is encoded so use

```
productName = productName.replace(/&lt;br&gt;/g," ");
```

note the `g` after the regular expression which means globally, to match all occurrences.

demo at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/VDxHx/

Comment: Thx that did the trick, sorry everyone for being misleading initially.

Answer (score 19):

Using regular expression you can use this pattern

```
/(<|&lt;)br\s*\/*(>|&gt;)/g
productName = productName.replace(/(<|&lt;)br\s*\/*(>|&gt;)/g,' ');
```

That pattern matches

```
 <br>, <br />,<br/>,<br     />,<br  >,
 or &lt;br&gt;, &lt;br/&gt;, &lt;br /&gt;
```

etc...

Comment: When all else failed, this succeeded!

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `g` flag in your regular expression. This indicates that the replace will be performed globally on all occurrences and not only on the first one.

```
productName = productName.replace(/\<br\>/g," ");
```

Of course you should be aware that this won't replace `<br/>` nor `<br />` but only `<br>`.

See an [example](http://ideone.com/zqyuK) of this working on ideone.

---

UPDATE:

Now that you've provided an example with your input here's a working regex you might use to replace:

```
productName = productName.replace(/&lt;br&gt;/g, ' ');
```

Comment: +1 for the solution, but a few words to explain why the flag is meaningful (and what it is) wouldn't perhaps hurt.

Comment: @nikc: Don’t you know how to access the language documentation?

Comment: @user357034: Don’t escape the brackets.

Comment: @user357034, of course it works: `'hello <br> and another <br> dfdskj'.replace(/\<br\>/g, ' ')` prints exactly what is expected. Probably your string doesn't contain `<br>`. See my remark about `<br/>` and `<br />`. Could this be the case?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: It seems, that the OP's code is somehow quoted. So, nope, in that case it doesn't work.

Comment: @Boldewyn, well then let's leave the OP explain his exact scenario and provide more details.

Comment: What are you escaping the brackets for?

Comment: @Darin - I hope you don't mind, I linked to an ideone example of your solution to show that it works in a concrete way.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, I can indeed. That doesn't hinder me from writing elaborate answers. I even know how to insert a link to the relevant entry in the manual, in order to propagate that knowledge further.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested it but you could try something like this

```
productName.replace(/\<br\>/g,' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I am sure it will work.

productName.replace(/</?br>/g, "");