# JQuery - Change Color of String in a Text, ignoring <br>'s between

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I need to change the color of a specific sub-string in a text.
The text looks like this:

```
SOME TE<br>
XT IS HER<br>
E.
```

I tired the `.replace()` function from jquery, the problem with it is, that, as you can see above, the text is splited with those `<br>`'s. How can I "ignore" them ?
For example I want to replace the String `TEXT` with `<span class="color-red">TEXT</span>`

Does anyone has an idea on how to solve this problem ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146648/jquery-find-text-and-replace. refer this

Comment: why do you need br's in the first place?

Comment: @madalinivascu It's because of design

Comment: @Ish Thanks for your refering, but this question is not very helpful because they don't have the problem with the <br>'s between the words

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184272/remove-all-br-from-a-string. Try this to remove the <br> or any other tag from the string and then replace with span

Comment: there you go -- https://jsfiddle.net/37bzjz5z/ -- you will have to find TE and XT if you know where the Breaks are --- https://jsfiddle.net/qyrf7hrp/

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery required. Although I did not test this at all so it might need tweaking.

```
var customReplace = function(str, subStr, color) {
    var words = str.split(' ');
    for (var i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var word = words[i].replace(/<br>/g, '');
        if (word === subStr) {
            words[i] = '<span class="color-' + color + '">' + words[i] + '</span>';
        }
    }

    return words.join('');
}
```

Comment: Wow, looks good. But how exactly can I use it? what is the str, and what is the subStr ?

Comment: Woops just realized this can be a lot simpler

Comment: subStr is the string you're trying to find and color. Str is the entire string e.g. `SOME TE<br>XT IS HER<br>E.` Just pass in the `innerHTML` for the str and set the `innerHtml` as the output of this function.

Comment: I tried this code `var textContent = $(".text-3-colors p").text();
    
    alert(customReplace(textContent,"saf","red"));` But it gives me an error: cannot read property replace of undefiend

Comment: So, now there's no error, but the subStr won't get colored red?

Comment: did you create the css classes? If you have Inspect the html and make sure the classes are being added correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think a good Idea could be something like following:

1. fine all text nodes and wrap them inside a span§
2. re-insert all tags

```js
var ALL_TAGS_REGEX = /(.+)(<{1}\/{0,1}.+>{1})/g;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.body.innerHTML = document
    .body
    .innerHTML
    .replace(ALL_TAGS_REGEX, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>$2')
  ;
});
```

```css
.highlight { background: cyan; }
```

```html
I am a string,<br>
<div> something else but no text node</div>
Other text nodes at libitum
```

Answer (score -1):

< br > tag is break in line, color won't be applicable on < br > text, this would not accounted as normal text while final html render

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean <br>  is not a text so why you worrying about its text color

Comment: because, I want to replace a hole word, but this word ist broken by a <br>. This <br> makes it hard to replace the word because for Example the .replace("text", "other text") won't replace my "text" because it is broken by a <br> -> "te<br>xt"

Comment: oh , problem is replacement of  text with ignoring <br>?

Comment: why you don't use , $(#<elementID>).empty() , then  $(#<elementID>).append("text") ?

Comment: could you explain the .empty() ?

Comment: emty() would flush the your html element contents , for example if <span> abc <br> foo bar</span> then it make it empty <span></span>. now you free to add any content/text as child!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122639/discussion-between-shashi-pandey-and-balex).